# Timeout sending http request via cellular but ok with WiFi

Tags: ios, swift, alamofire

I am having this trouble for quite sometime now. I was trying to send out http requests via WiFi and everything seems to be fine but when I switched to Cellular the requests always timeout.

I have tried to use both synchronous call, async call and use NSRULSession instead of NSURLConnection, get the same result, any suggestions? My assumption is at the network API level, the connectivity differences shouldn't be exposed to the user.

Additionally I've tried to use Apple's Reachability module to check and both WWAN and WiFi are reachable. I am using xcode 6.1 and iOS7, iOS8.0.1 and iOS8.1.

PS. I am using Alamofire module to send the requests, here's the error message I got:

```
Error Domain=NSURLErrorDomain
Code=-1001 "The operation couldn’t be completed. (NSURLErrorDomain error -1001.)"
UserInfo=0x17007a880
{
  NSErrorFailingURLStringKey=http://www.testsite.com:8080/carservices/CloseCar,
  NSUnderlyingError=0x170059650 "The operation couldn’t be completed.
  (kCFErrorDomainCFNetwork error -1001.)",
  NSErrorFailingURLKey=http://www.testsite.com:8080/carservices/CloseCar
}
```

Here's a trace route I captured from my phone to the site via AT&T 4G network. The site I am trying to access is hosted on Amazon AWS with a elastic IP address.

```
1 172.26.96.169 (172.26.96.169) 346.630 ms 471.051 ms 473.139 ms
2 172.26.96.9 (172.26.96.9) 232.148 ms 368.511 ms 369.776 ms
3 172.16.126.100 (172.16.126.100) 312.747 ms 628.247 ms 631.752 ms
4 12.249.2.49 (12.249.2.49) 462.616 ms 916.701 ms 919.660 ms
5 12.83.180.82 (12.83.180.82) 348.677 ms 503.967 ms 506.960 ms
6 12.122.114.29 (12.122.114.29) 99.483 ms 202.542 ms 205.154 ms
7 192.205.37.58 (192.205.37.58) 63.011 ms 691.055 ms 693.907 ms
8 ae-7.r21.snjsca04.us.bb.gin.ntt.net (129.250.7.54) 66.330 ms 82.107 ms 137.337 ms
9 ae-3.r20.sttlwa01.us.bb.gin.ntt.net (129.250.3.125) 74.185 ms 84.449 ms 99.471 ms
10 ae-1.r04.sttlwa01.us.bb.gin.ntt.net (129.250.5.43) 112.387 ms 126.747 ms 29.141 ms
11 ae-5.amazon.sttlwa01.us.bb.gin.ntt.net (198.104.202.190) 72.229 ms 81.840 ms 04.535 ms
12 205.251.225.200 (205.251.225.200) 105.630 ms 287.484 ms 290.750 ms
13 205.251.232.92 (205.251.232.92) 111.903 ms 196.493 ms 197.762 ms
14 205.251.232.153 (205.251.232.153) 458.479 ms * 0.316 ms
15 54.239.48.181 (54.239.48.181) 575.475 ms 736.233 ms 738.883 ms
16  * * *
17  * * *
18  * * *
19  * * *
20  * * *
21  * * *
```

Comment: Try to use phone as an access point and troubleshoot connection with the standard desktop tools.

Comment: @A-Live Could you elaborate more on this? I am currently using my iPhone6 as test device, run the app on this phone with WiFi ON and no problem, everything works fine. However once I turn the WiFi off so it's on cellular network, the request times out....

Comment: Try [this](http://www.wikihow.com/Activate-Internet-Tethering-on-the-iPhone) instructions to share your mobile internet to be used on Mac, then use Network Utility from /Applications/Utilities/. If you aren't able to share internet with an iPhone another kind of phone or usb gsm modem might let you do the same thing. My guess is that somewhere the connection is getting blocked due to different network settings.

Comment: @A-Live It's exactly as what you've predicted!! When I try to use my phone as a tethering device, the REST request I sent from my laptop REST client( I am using postman) timed out, but strangely I can still load webpages....any suggestions?

Comment: it depends on who owns and configures your backend, but you can always at least try to check the route and/or contact tech support.

Comment: @A-Live I found something interesting today. The site can't even be accessed with Safari over cellular network, while if WiFi is switched back on, it loads pages really fast. I wonder if there is anything for example some practices that if you are requesting over cellular, it tries https first? or simply because through WiFi certain fields of the header get filled while if through cellular, they get filled differently....

Comment: @A-Live btw I have control of the backend. and thank you for helping out, really appreciate it.

Comment: No, it actually looks like a routing issue, your mobile provider most likely have different route, try Network Utility.app with tethered cellular and wi-fi network and you'll most likely see different routes and the failing node somewhere in the middle. Unfortunately having control over the backend is not enough to change the route, it is built depending on the provider resources and preferences. If you add trace-routes for cellular and wi-fi connections somebody might be able to give a more useful hint on what to do next.

Comment: @A-Live here's the trace route I captured:     I've added it to the main post since it's quite long.

Comment: well you even have options now: contact at&t or contact amazon. or just wait until whatever is broken gets fixed.

Comment: @A-Live thank you so much for this. I'll call AT&T first to follow up. I guess the problem resides on their side. For now, I am creating a virtual tunnel through third party service and my request finally reached the site. :-)

Comment: @YaoZhai do you remember how you solved this issue? I am facing the same issue with AT&T right now.